# ODBC Driver or .NET DataProvider for Centura SQLbase needed

Tags: .net, odbc, dataprovider, centura, sqlbase

For a Customer we need to import data from an old

```
Centura SQLBase 7.5.1
```

database. The best way would be to connect directly from .Net to the customers database, but I can't find a driver or .Net Connector to use.

So far I found out that the company behind the product is currently: http://www.unify.com/
But before I contact them, is there a freely available driver / connector for SQLBase available?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was hard to find, but eventually I found the download:

http://support.guptatechnologies.com/supportwiki/index.php/SQLBase_Driver_Packs

You have to query your favorite search engine for "SQLBase Driver Packs" instead of ".NET Data Provider" to get a result.
The Setup contains ODBC/.NET/OLEDB and JDBC drivers.

That said, I could not connect to my database anyway, because the installer (I tried the 9.0.1 and the 10.0.0 setup) is broken.

The was not able to get the 10.0.0 to work but for the 9.x version I manually copied these files:

```
- SQLBaseUtil.dll
- MFC71.dll
- msvcr71.dll
- msvcp71.dll
```

from the installation path to my system32 folder. That worked for Windows XP and Windows 7, but for Windows 7 I also needed to define the path to the ini file in  the connectionstring:

```
var connectionString = "data source=ISLAND;" +
                       "uid=sysadm;pwd=sysadm;" +
                       "ini=C:\\Program Files\\Gupta\\SQLBase901\\sql.ini";
```